# SwipeToDismissBox change direction

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to implement closing the Dialog by swiping from top to bottom, but in SwipeToDismissBox there are only StartToEnd and EndToStart.
Is it possible to change the direction of SwipeToDismissBox from top to bottom?

link to the official source:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/compose/material/SwipeToDismissBoxState.

Comment: Swiping to dismiss is always left or right in Android. You might be able to implement that behaviour yourself, but I don't recommend it. Consistency between apps is important.